# What happens to whitelighters or elders when they are "killed"?

Tags: charmed

In the TV series "Charmed", what happens to an elder or a whitelighter when they are "killed"? Do they just reappear unharmed some time later, are they recycled or reincarnated in some way or are they destroyed for ever?